# Appending Dictionary Objects within a Master Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary, iterator

I am attempting to append multiple dictionary objects to one master dictionary containing each individual item.

```py
object_thing = [{'id1': 'x'}, {'id2': 'y'}]

master_dict = {}

for thing in object_thing:
  master_dict.update(thing)


print(master_dict)
```

I would like the result to be:

```sh
{{'id1': 'x'},{'id2': 'y'}}
```

and not:

```sh
{'id1': 'x', 'id2': 'y'}
```

Also is it possible to append a single dictionary object to a master dictionary as well?

Comment: The result you are looking for is not a dict... It is a set. And you already have the dicts in a list so is there really a reason to do that?

Comment: A dictionary has key-value pairs.  Your desired result `{{'id1': 'x'},{'id2': 'y'}}` doesn't look like a dictionary, but a set.  But that can't be a set, because its members, dictionaries, are of an unhashable type.

Comment: how do you want to access this data later? this will help determine the best way to store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a set not a dict, but a set can't have dicts as elements since they're unhashable, so either use a dict with keys as numbers (or strings, or something hashable that identifies the inner dicts):

```
master_dict = {}

for i, thing in enumerate(object_thing):
  master_dict[i] = thing


print(master_dict)
```

Output:

```
{0: {'id1': 'x'}, 1: {'id2': 'y'}}
```

Or, just stick with using a list.

Comment: @Tomerikoo *Facepalm* (completely missed that).